# Вывод торговых предложении в строгой последоввательности id

Tags: сортировка, битрикс

Вот проблема следующего содержания. Из  1с в промежуточную базу (не битрикс)  выгружаются данные. А из промеж. базы в битрикс.  У товара и торгового предложения есть одна базовая цена, других типов цен нет.  Цена меняется с помощью наценок, выгруженных из 1c для каждого пользователя, бренда, и, наконец ,товара, в промежуточную таблицу,- идет запрос в эту промеж. табл, и вызывается `GetOptimalPrice` (вызывается с помощью обработчиков событии init.php в шаблоне компонента `catalog.section`). Таким образом, формируются новая цена, исходя из наценок этой промеж. таблицы. Вот , будем считать , что товар наш, а торговые предложения-товары поставщиков.Нужно сделать сортировку по цене. 1)хотела сделать через result_modifier.php (Он цену поменяет, но не факт, что будет работать сортировка), так как сначала идет вызов компонента-сортирует. Вопрос где в компоненте? Скопировала catalog_section в свое пространство имен. и давай смотреть. Вижу есть, `$rsElements = CIBlockElement::GetList($arSort, array_merge($arrFilter, $arFilter), false, $arNavParams, $arSelect);`. У меня фильтр в объявлении компонента имеет код

```
    "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD" => $field,
    "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER" => $order,
    "OFFERS_SORT_FIELD2" => "CATALOG_PRICE_1",
    "OFFERS_SORT_ORDER2" => "asc",
```

Вопрос где преопределить цену, не меняя саму базу (вроде result_modifier.php), чтобы выводилась отсортированная правильная цена. Как я поняла- штатная сортировка предполагает сортировку по товару, а внутри блока товара- по торговым предложениям. 2) Можно ли отсортировать торговые предложения функцией сортировки , и вывести торговые предложения в отсортированном порядке  с помощью GetList (id строго заданны по цене)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
//result_modifier.php
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die("err0");
//Make all properties present in order
foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $key => $arElement)
{
        /*Свойства*/
 $arRes = array();
 foreach($arParams["PROPERTY_CODE"] as $pid)
 {
  $arRes[$pid] = CIBlockFormatProperties::GetDisplayValue($arElement, $arElement["PROPERTIES"][$pid], "catalog_out");
 }
 $arResult["ITEMS"][$key]["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"] = $arRes;
        $quantity = 1; 
        $renewal = "N"; 
        // узнаем оптимальную цену методом GetOptimalPrice класса CCatalogProduct 
        $arPrice = CCatalogProduct::GetOptimalPrice($arElement["ID"], $quantity, $USER->GetUserGroupArray(), $renewal); 
        $arResult["ITEMS"][$key][CATALOG_PRICE_1]=$arPrice["PRICE"]["PRICE"];
        
        if(is_array($arElement["OFFERS"]) && !empty($arElement["OFFERS"])){
            foreach($arElement["OFFERS"] as $key2 => $arOffer) {
  $productID =$arOffer["ID"]; 
                $quantity = 1; 
                $renewal = "N"; 
                // узнаем оптимальную цену методом GetOptimalPrice класса CCatalogProduct 
                $arPrice = CCatalogProduct::GetOptimalPrice($arOffer["ID"], $quantity, $USER->GetUserGroupArray(), $renewal); 
                $arResult["ITEMS"][$key][OFFERS][$key2]["CATALOG_PRICE_1"]=$arPrice["PRICE"]["PRICE"];
            }
            if (($_REQUEST['method']=='asc')&&($_REQUEST['sort']=='price'))
                $arResult["ITEMS"][$key][OFFERS]=array_sort($arResult["ITEMS"][$key][OFFERS],'CATALOG_PRICE_1', SORT_ASC);
            if (($_REQUEST['method']=='desc')&&($_REQUEST['sort']=='price'))
                $arResult["ITEMS"][$key][OFFERS]=array_sort($arResult["ITEMS"][$key][OFFERS],'CATALOG_PRICE_1', SORT_DESC);
        }      
}
?>
```

кому пригодится, долго мучилась....